# How to encrypt with SHA1 in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, encryption

I have following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"

bucket="mybucket"
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="image/png"
dateValue="Thu, 10 Mar 2016 04:13:24 +0545"
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
vs3Key="AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
s3Secret="/Wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
echo $signature
```

I want to write this same code in nodejs. This is what I have written so far, but the signature is not valid:

```
'use strict';

var secret= '/Wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var file = process.argv[2];
var crypto = require('crypto');
var dateValue = 'Thu, 10 Mar 2016 04:13:24 +0545';
var bucket = "mybucket";
var resource = "/" + bucket + "/" + file;
var contentType = "image/png";
var stringToSign = "PUT\n\n"+contentType+"\n"+dateValue+"\n"+resource;
var s3Key = "AKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha1", secret).update(stringToSign).digest('hex');
console.log(new Buffer(hmac).toString('base64'));
```

Comment: Remember SHA1 is a *hashing* method, not an encryption method. Encryption can be undone. Hashing is designed to be impossible or impractical to undo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bash code is calling `openssl` with the `-binary` argument, so you should be doing the same in the JS code.

According to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding):

> ### `hash.digest([encoding])`
>
> Calculates the digest of all of the data passed to be hashed (using the `hash.update()` method). The `encoding` can be `'hex'`, `'binary'` or `'base64'`. If `encoding` is provided a string will be returned; otherwise a `Buffer` is returned.

Comment: So in the bash there is binary argument which is then piped to base64 right? So should I convert the final hash to base64?

Comment: Seems like that should do it. Not sure. Possibly the `base64` option would do both at once.